# .dmg that expands like a .zip

Tags: macos, zip, dmg

I swear that I've seen Mac OS X applications distributed as .dmg's that, when opened, expand and leave the application in place (deleting the .dmg) instead of mounting a virtual disk.

How are these auto-expanding .dmg archives created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an "internet-enabled" disk image. It's basically a normal disk image, but with a special setting that says it should be expanded rather than mounted. You can create one by making a standard disk image, then running:

```
hdiutil internet-enable /path/to/image.dmg
```

You can reverse this with:

```
hdiutil internet-enable -no /path/to/image.dmg
```

See the [hdiutil man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) for more info. Also, [this page](http://macstuff.beachdogs.org/blog/?p=29) has an AppleScript to automate the process.